# cassandra uuid and keycloak id

Tags: cassandra, keycloak

Is it safe to store a keycloak id as an uuid type in cassandra or should I just go with text? After reading a bit on uuid it seems like it's a [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) so it should be safe. However I'm not reading anywhere that keycloak use that standard. I did try a couple id's from keycloak and they were working though but I wouldn't like it to stop working half way through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keycloak appears to use java.util.UUID, which is the standard, and should be safe to store in cassandra as a UUID.